# Problem with this code to test the Credentials?

Tags: c#, credentials, webrequest, httpwebresponse

I wrote this method to test for credentials but I dunno why when it goes to the GetResponse method is actually goes and runs the webservice. I just want it to test if the credentials for that web service are correct or not.

```
   private bool TestCredentials(string sURL, ref  string sUsername, ref  string sPassword)
    {

        bool retVal = false;
        CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();
        myCache.Add(new Uri(sURL), "Full", new NetworkCredential(sUsername, sPassword, "our_domain"));

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sURL);
        request.Credentials = myCache;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            retVal = true;
        return retVal;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't know if the credentials are good without some kind of communication with the server.  You could create a dummy URL to execute a test request against.  IE, an URL you can request that doesn't actually do anything on the server.

Comment: dummy URL? you mean instead of passing the real asmx address, I pass for example http://www.google.com ?  but still with the same credentials? but if you mean another url on that server, well this is the only url that we have at all.

Comment: Do you have any control over the server?  If you don't, there's not a lot you can do.  Making the request (IE, calling `GetResponse`) will execute the action.  What I was meaning was adding another function to the webservice that doesn't do anything.